# What's the success rate of Imiquimod Cream 5% recommended for the treatment of facial superficial basal cell carcinoma beyond 5 years post-treatment?

Tags: dermatology, treatment, basal-cell-carcinoma

I have read several studies on the success rate of Imiquimod Cream 5% for the treatment of facial superficial basal cell carcinoma, however none of them looked at beyond 5 years post-treatment. E.g. {2} looked at 1-year post-treatment and {1} looked at 5-year post-treatment.

What's the success rate of Imiquimod Cream 5% recommended for the treatment of facial superficial basal cell carcinoma beyond 5 years post-treatment?

---

References:

- {1} Bath-Hextall, Fiona, Mara Ozolins, Sarah J. Armstrong, Graham B. Colver, William Perkins, Paul SJ Miller, and Hywel C. Williams. "Surgical excision versus imiquimod 5% cream for nodular and superficial basal-cell carcinoma (SINS): a multicentre, non-inferiority, randomised controlled trial." The lancet oncology 15, no. 1 (2014): 96-105. https://doi.org/10.1016/S1470-2045(13)70530-8
- {2} Arits, A.H., Mosterd, K., Essers, B.A., Spoorenberg, E., Sommer, A., De Rooij, M.J., van Pelt, H.P., Quaedvlieg, P.J., Krekels, G.A., van Neer, P.A. and Rijzewijk, J.J., 2013. Photodynamic therapy versus topical imiquimod versus topical fluorouracil for treatment of superficial basal-cell carcinoma: a single blind, non-inferiority, randomised controlled trial. The lancet oncology, 14(7), pp.647-654. https://doi.org/10.1016/S1470-2045(13)70143-8